# Means and Covariances of powers of a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance, means, variance

Let $X$ be a normally distributed random variable, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Consider a random vector 
$$V = \left[ X^n, X^{n-1}, \dots, X^2, X, 1 \right]^T $$ 
What is the expected value of $V$, $\bar{V}$, and covariance matrix $\Sigma$? Do they have any nice properties?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) has a listing of the the first eight non-central moments of a normal distribution, which I believe should be the expected values. Is that right?

Comment: Backwards, yes. As to the covariances, they are $E(X^{i+j})-E(X_i)E(X_j)$, so (for a short while) can be obtained from the Wikipedia entries. Moments *about the mean* are reasonably nice, but moments about the origin are a bit of a mess.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for some nice structural properties within the covariance matrix but I guess not.

Comment: You are welcome. Just because I do not know of any does not mean there aren't!